# Threads getting into blocked state while doing a host name look up using java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost

Tags: java, performance, https, tomcat9, inetaddress

Please find below the application/environment details where the problem is seen.

- Java Web application deployed on Tomcat 9.0.35 with JRE Version 1.8.0_231-b11
- The application is running in a docker container deployed on Open shift Kubernetes Distribution platform.

I see lot of threads in the application are getting into a BLOCKED state sometimes for few mins. On  thread dump analysis, it was found that java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost call is taking too much time. Lot of threads are getting stuck here. The host name is fetched for every logger printed in the application.

The issue is  intermittent. But when it occurs, the application/tomcat will go into a paused state which leads to the accumulation of lot of threads. After some time(few seconds), all the blocked threads are unblocked simultaneously. Because of the request concurrency, the application will run out of DB connections which it maintains in the pool leading to issues/slowness/service availability. As a fix, I have made sure to access the host name only once into a static variable and use the same throughout the logging process. I wanted to know the detailed root cause of this issue.

- Why this issue is occurring intermittently?
- Is there a problem with DNS look up in this kubernetes environment?
- We are using IPV4 protocol/addresses
- Are there any better approaches/fixes to handle this issue?

Sample below from the thread dump:

```
 "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-13" #95 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fccadbba800 nid=0xaf5 waiting for monitor entry 0x00007fcb912d1000
       java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1486)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000005e71878a0> (a java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 5):

In JDK 8, `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` works [as follows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/d5c320d784e5/src/share/classes/java/net/InetAddress.java#l1471):

1. Obtain host name as a string via native [gethostname](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) call.
2. If there was less than 5 seconds since the last host name resolution, return the cached IP address.
3. Otherwise resolve the host name:

   - using JDK built-in lookup cache, which has the default TTL equal to 30 seconds;
   - using the system call, which performs an actual DNS lookup (depending on the configuration, the address may be further cached by the OS and DNS servers).
4. Cache the resolved local host IP address for 5 seconds.

Steps 2-4 are performed under the global [`cacheLock`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/d5c320d784e5/src/share/classes/java/net/InetAddress.java#l1486). If something goes wrong during this process, all threads calling `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` will block at this lock - exactly what you observe.

Usually local host name resolution does not end up in a network call, as long as the host address is hard-coded in `/etc/hosts`. But in your case it seems like the real network requests are involved (whenever TTL expires). And when the first DNS request times out (UDP is not a reliable protocol after all), a delay happens.

The solution is to configure `/etc/hosts` to contain the name and the address of the local host, e.g.

```
192.168.1.23   myhost.mydomain
```

where `myhost.mydomain` is the same string as returned by `hostname` command.

Finally, if the host name is not expected to change while the application is running, caching it once and forever on the application level looks like a good fix.

Comment: Thank you. This information helps. Yes, I am loading the hostname only once and caching it. I have rolled out this fix to production and we are not seeing these thread blocking issues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I am loading the hostname only once and caching it during the application start up. I have rolled out this fix to production and we are not seeing the thread blocking issues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe server is going to look using ipv6 and if is not in use you can configure JVM to use only IPV4, to do so add this to the options -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true or if only need ipv6 -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true. This will force JVM to use the right protocol.